# "Student ... Business Administration". What preposition?

Tags: expressions, vocabulary

how could I paraphrase "I am studying Business Administration" to "I am a student ... Business Administration".
And how could I paraphrase "I am studying for my undergraduate degree" to "I am a student ...". 
What prepositions or other help words would work?

Thanks

Comment: *of* is common, *in* is possible. See also: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/153459/graduate-student-in-or-of.

Comment: Alternatively, you could also say "I'm a Business Administration student." (If you're going for a master's in the subject, "I'm an MBA student." will make sense to most Americans).

Answer (score 1):

You could say you are a **student *of* Business Administration** or a **student *in* Business Administration**.  The former is both more formal and less clear than the latter.

You can paraphrase "I am studying for my undergraduate degree" as,

> I am an **undergraduate student**

or just,

> I'm an **undergraduate**

or even more colloquially,

> I'm an **undergrad**.

(The same trick works with your previous question: you can say you are a **Business Administration student**.)